# Verifying Google OpenID response

Tags: php, codeigniter, openid

I'm trying to implement Google OpenID into  my site, but the server has several restrictions so I can not use file_get_contents().

For that reason I'm unable to use many of the libraries available.

How should I go about verifying Google's response?

I haven't gotten this to work: [how to verify google openid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957358/how-to-verify-google-openid-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that the server restrictions does prevent you from access remote URL all together. If so, then it would be impossible to verify the OpenID response as the whole point of a third-party authorization system is to verify user identity from a **third-party**. You have to be able to talk to the third party anyway.

Many PHP functions enables you to fetch remote content, `fopen('http(s)://')` is one thing, `curl` functions is another, even `system('curl')` or `system('wget')`. You need to get this working first.