# OpenID Fake request to return_to url

Tags: php, curl, openid, google-openid

After openID `checkid_setup` the provider redirects to `return_to` with a set of `GET` params.  It may be post too, I am not sure, however google returns all GET. Anyways that doesn't matter.

What If someone makes a fake request to `return_to`?

Right now I've planned to attach a salted hash of `assoc_handle` with the `return_to` url
Is there any better way ?

*(I am doing just to steps `associate` and then `checkid_setup` am I missing any additional steps to conform with other services or even with google ? though I am getting `identity` and `claimed_id` with my existing process)*

Comment: http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995230/Security

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to verify google openid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957358/how-to-verify-google-openid-response)

Comment: This is not duplicate. Cause what I am asking is *is my `right now` solution Okay ?* and there is another question in italicized. none of them is answered in any of your links. So your claim is wrong. and there may be others scratching for the same problem. so they may also need the question to live. So this should not be closed either.

Comment: Please read *possible*. However, *your* right now solution might be too localized ;). So probably you should outline more specifically why the general suggestions that exists for your problem (and which have been addressed in the past) do not fit for *your right now* approach. That would clarify your question as well which would be a benefit for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

The spec covers this -- http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#verification

If you're using PHP as in the question tag, just use the php-openid library. It correctly verifies assertions and has been well vetted & tested.

If you're justing asking out of curiosity to better understand OpenID, great. But please do **not** try implementing your own relying party library unless you're confident that you can do it correctly and not introduce vulnerabilities. It's hard to get right, and very easy to get wrong :)